# Simplifying recursive function (and making it more functional)

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming

I have this recursive function which is meant to recursively go through levels of container objects and check if they are open. At the same time I need to return a counter which is incremented for each level of nested container which has a container that isn't open.

So the container structure might look something like this (however the function needs to be dynamic):

```
container {
    open: true,
    containers: [
        {
            open: false,
            containers: [

                    {
                        open: false,
                        containers: [

                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        open: false,
                        containers: [

                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        open: false,
                        containers: [

                        ]
                    },
            ]
        },
        {
            open: true,
            containers: [

                    {
                        open: false,
                        containers: [

                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        open: true,
                        containers: [

                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        open: false,
                        containers: [

                        ]
                    },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently I've written a function that will traverse 4 levels of containers to do the check, but I'd like to make it keep going for as long as it can.

```
function checkChildren(container) {
      var x = 0;
      if(closedCheck(container)) {
        x++;
        if(loopCheck(closedCheck(container), closedCheck)) {
          x++;
          if(loopCheck(loopCheck(closedCheck(container), closedCheck), closedCheck)) {
            x++;
            if(loopCheck(loopCheck(loopCheck(closedCheck(container), closedCheck), closedCheck), closedCheck)) {
              x++;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      return x;

      function closedCheck(container) {
        if(typeof container.containers !== 'undefined') {
          return container.containers.filter(function(val) {
            return val.open === false;
          })
        } else return false;
      }

      function loopCheck(containers, callback) {
        return containers.filter(callback);
      }
    }
```

t goes through each level of container. So for example the first level is the root container.containers. The second level includes the 'containers' array in each of those containers in the first level. For each level that has a container which 'open === false' a counter is incremented. A counter, in this case, is a number which is increased or decreased according to an iteration or condition. The expected output is a number that represents that counter. So if I were to call this function for the root container. The result would be 2 since two levels down there is a closed container.

Does anyone have an idea on how to simplify that and make it more dynamic?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: "a counter which is incremented for each level of nested container which has a container that isn't open'

Comment: @Rorschach120: I'm sure that makes perfect sense to you, but it isn't to anybody else. Can you explain it a little more clearly? For the example you gave, what is you function supposed to do and what is the output supposed to be? Is it `2`? or `3`? or `6`?

Comment: It goes through each level of container. So for example the first level is the root container.containers. The second level includes the 'containers' array in each of those containers in the first level. For each level that has a container which 'open === false' a counter is incremented. A counter, in this case, is a number which is increased or decreased according to an iteration or condition. The expected output is a number that represents that counter. So if I were to call this function for the root container. The result would be 2 since two levels down there is a closed container.

Comment: `The result would be 2 since two levels down there is a closed container.` That really doesn't jive with what you initially said. It sounds like you just want to know how many levels deep is the *deepest* closed container. Is that correct? Even if that container is itself in a closed container?

Comment: Yes. That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Except the last part. If a container's parent is closed then that container will have to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
function findDeepest(obj,lvl) {
    if (!obj) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (!obj.open) {
        return lvl;
    }
    if (!obj.containers || !obj.containers.length) {
        return 0;
    }
    var subTrees = obj.containers.map(function (item) {
        return findDeepest(item,lvl+1);
    });
    return Math.max.apply(Math, subTrees);
}

console.log(findDeepest(container ,0));
```

The idea is that we start at the top (level 0) and if that object is open, we then go down all it's children until we find closed containers, then we pick the max (i.e. deepest) of those and return it.

Comment: Thanks, this is really close. Although I need for it to keep checking even if the container is closed. So sorry, my comment was incorrect, in a bit of a brain stew.  


I am initializing all of these containers, and ones that are set to 'open: false' are closed, but I have a problem of parent containers trying to close at the same time as their children and breaking things. So I have a '$timeout' which contains a 'closeContainer()' function, but the timeout time is set to 'checkChildren(container) * 30'. 


if the function returns at 'if(!obj.open)' it will never get to the subTrees.